# How can I find a matching remote branch by name?

Tags: bash, git, branch

Say I have a local branch `test` which tracks a remote branch `remote/test`. Then at some point I delete the local branch. How can I find the matching remote branch by name `'test'`?

P.S. It seems that I need something similar to what [`git checkout [<branch>]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt) does for non-existent local branches.

Comment: You can use `git branch -r | grep "test"` to show all the remote branches with name test.

Comment: A remote branch does not necessarily has a similar name as the local branch. So, in general it might not possible.

Comment: @Serge I think, searching for the same name branch is ok. However, there must be only one remote with such branch.

Answer (score 0):

Using `git branch` with `-r` and `-l` options seems to produce the desired output:

```
git branch -r -l '*branch_name*'
```

I wonder if there's a reliable way to split the name to remote name and branch name parts though (considering the remote name might contain slashes).